# Get JSON value from curl request

Tags: json, shell, curl

I have a Nexus Repository server where my artifacts are stored. I want to write a shell script to download artifacts from here. When using the curl request `curl --user username:password -X GET "http://your_ip:your_port/service/rest/v1/search?repository=your_repository" -H "accept: application/json"` I get a list of the items in my repository which looks like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "dGVzdC1hcHA6ZDM1MTBiN2FkMThkODJjZGU1NjNhMWVlMWFmOWIwMGQ",
      "repository": "test-app",
      "format": "maven2",
      "group": "no.ahj",
      "name": "test-app",
      "version": "1.0-20190715.130341-2",
      "assets": [
        {
          "downloadUrl": "http://192.168.56.2:8081/repository/test-app/no/ahj/test-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-app-1.0-20190715.130341-2.pom",
          "path": "no/ahj/test-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-app-1.0-20190715.130341-2.pom",
          "id": "dGVzdC1hcHA6Yzc3MDE2OWMwYjJlM2VkODU0MGMyOGEwOWQ0Njk4ZTQ",
          "repository": "test-app",
          "format": "maven2",
          "checksum": {
            "sha1": "5fd032774dd3ae6fbbd6484b3dc6ef2582d9b397",
            "md5": "3a6aa8e295a734fdb8a8df782c0a14d5"
          }
        },
```

I would like my shell script to run this curl request, extract the value from the `downloadURL` field, store it in some variable and then use `wget` with this variable to download the file. So my question is this: How can I take the URL from `downloadURL` and store/use it in my shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to parse it with likely no external dependencies (as python is installed by default on most Linux distributions) is just to use python:

```
user@host ~ % JSON=$(curl --user username:password -X GET "http://your_ip:your_port/service/rest/v1/search?repository=your_repository" -H "accept: application/json")
user@host ~ % echo $JSON | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["items"][0]["assets"][0]["downloadUrl"])'
http://192.168.56.2:8081/repository/test-app/no/ahj/test-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-app-1.0-20190715.130341-2.pom
```

If you are going to do a lot of JSON parsing in this script, it may be worth considering writing the entire script in Python, too, instead of shell script.

Comment: Thanks Zaroth. When running your commands in my script it does indeed print the downloadURL. but when I try to store it like this: `URL=$JSON | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["items"][0]["assets"][0]["downloadUrl"])'` I get an error saying something like "No JSON object could be decoded". It does not work to replace `echo` with `wget` either.

Comment: if you want to store output of a command in a variable, you need to surround it in `$()` or `\`\`` - see and compare your command storing `URL=` and my command storing `JSON=`

Comment: Hmm, I still get the same error when doing `URL=$($JSON | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["items"][0]["assets"][0]["downloadUrl"])')`

Comment: you also forgot `echo` as in `echo $JSON` - see my answer